# Is there a difference between a spigot and a faucet (usage in AmE)

Tags: expressions, american-english, pragmatics

What is a **domestic tap** called commonly in the US ?

-a spigot?

- a device that controls the flow of liquid from a large container (MW)

Dictionary meaning aside, I had this understanding that a domestic tap is known as a faucet.

Comment: In order of common usage that I have heard in my lifetime, I would list them as: (1) tap, (2) faucet, (3) nozzle, and (4) spigot.

Comment: I would swap (1) and (2), but otherwise the same. There are specializations: _nozzles_ expel water under pressure, and therefore are attached to hoses. _Tap_ has a secondary meaning from brewing and cooperage, and gets extended metaphorically for other fluids, like electricity. _Spigot_ is part of the brewing/cooperage sense of _tap_; it's the tool that is used to tap a barrel, and it also gets called the tap after it's been inserted and is being used to draw off the contents. _Faucet_ is the name of the fixture that gets installed over a sink.

Comment: See [spigot vs faucet vs tap](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105943/what-do-you-call-an-indoor-water-tap/105960#105960)

Comment: The only reason why I rank *tap* so highly on my list is that, as a kid, my parents used to frequently say "Turn off the tap!".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if the rest of the country uses this, but.....Around here, the difference is more esoteric.  A spigot is more functional, less decorative than a faucet.  Our garden hose is attached to a spigot, but the kitchen sink has a faucet.

Comment: In Oregon, I regularly hear this distinction made.  Hoses are attached to spigots, while sinks/tubs get faucets.

Comment: Yeah, either will be understood in most contexts, but usually a faucet designed to have a hose attached is referred to as a "spigot".  And regionally "tap" may be more common than "faucet".

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely subject to regional variation. Regarding "spigot", see http://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/q_41.html

I don't know of studies on "faucet" or "tap", but I'll bet they're subject to regional variation as well.